# SAP Portal: SAP Universal Worklist Items Cache - Clear Cache option not working (runs continuously)

Tags: cache, sap

When I click on the 'Clear Cache' option within the SAP Portal UWL I get a 'working' dialogue box (spinning icon), even after an hour.

This normally works (and takes less than 10 seconds).

Any ideas why it is not working now?